# Cucumber - run same feature a number of times depending on records in a database

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake

I have a cucumber feature that checks a website has processed payment files correctly  (BACS,SEPA, FPS etc). The first stage of the process is to create the payment files which in-turn create expected result data in a database. This data is then used to validate against the payment processing website.

If I process one file, my feature works perfectly validating the expected results. Where I'm stuck is how I get the feature to run (n) number of times depending on the number of records/files that were originally processed.

I've tried an 'Around' hook using a record count iteration with no joy, can't see how I can fit it into an outline scenario and now think that perhaps a rake task to call the feature might work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a sample of the feature:

Feature: Processing SEPA Credit Transfer Files. Same Day Value Payments.

```
Background:
    Given we want to test the "SEPA_Regression" scenario suite  
        And that we have processed a "SEPA" file from the "LDN" branch
        And we plan to use the "ITA1" environment 
    Then we log in to "OPF" as a "SEPA Department" user

@feature @find_and_check_sepa_interchange @all_rows
Scenario:   Receive SEPA Credit Transfer Files for branch
    Given that we are on the "Payment Management > Interchanges" page
    When I search for our Interchange with the following search parameters:
        | Field Name |
        | Transport Date From |
        | Bank |
        | Interchange Reference |
    Then I can check the following fields for the given file in the "Interchanges" table:
        | Field Name|
        | Interchange Reference |
        | Transport Date |
        | File Name |
        | File Format |
        | Clearing Participant |
        | Status |
        | Direction |
        | Bank |
    When I select the associated "Interchange Id" link
    Then the "Interchange Details" page is displayed
```

**Update** I've implemented nested steps for the feature so that I can call the database records first and feed each set of records (or at least the row id) into the main feature like so:

Feature

```
@trial_feature 
Scenario:   Validate multiple Files
    Given we have one or more records in the database to process for the "SEPA_Regression" scenario
    Then we can validate each file against the system
```

Feature steps:

```
Then(/^we can validate each file against the system$/) do
x = 0
while x <= $interchangeHash.count - 1
    $db_row = x
    # Get the other sets of data using the file name in the query       
    id = $interchangeHash[x]['id']
    file_name = $interchangeHash[x]['CMS_Unique_Reference_Id']
    Background.get_data_for_scenario(scenario, file_name)
    steps %{
    Given that we are on the "Payment Management > Interchanges" page
        When I search for our Interchange with the following search parameters:
            | Field Name |
            | Transport Date From |
            | Bank |
            | Interchange Reference |
        Then I can check the following fields for the given file in the "Interchanges" table:
            | Field Name|
            | Interchange Reference |
            | Transport Date |
            | File Name |
            | File Format |
            | Clearing Participant |
            | Status |
            | Direction |
            | Bank |
        When I select the associated "Interchange Id" link
        Then the "Interchange Details" page is displayed
```

Seems a bit of a 'hack' but it works.

Comment: Hi Milton! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you explain more specifically how the program currently works? Perhaps by adding the code you use now and some psudo-code of how you want it to work?

Comment: @thesecretmaster - for some reason the initial stackoverflow question form is blocked by my company so I had to write it on my phone. Looks as though I can comment though so here goes:

It's just a basic cucumber feature that logs in to the website and using watir validates data in the dom. As mentioned, if I have just one record all is well. If I have 2 records in the database, I don't know how to get the feature to process a second time.

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple loop work?

Comment: @thesecretmaster - have managed to edit original question with sample of the feature. Can't see where I can place a loop, each `Given, When Then` feature steps need to be exercised multiple times but you can't do this through the feature. Don't know how I can get it to 'know' that it's got to process n number of times.

Comment: I'm confused about how/when/why you get 2 records and why you can't just loop through them `Interchange.all.length` times

Comment: Basically, cucumber doesn't work like this, each of the Gherkin statements, the `Given, When, Then` are converted to individual feature steps that I then fill with code to fulfil them. So each are individually executed in sequence. So when it hits `Given that we are on the "Payment Management > Interchanges" page` it exercises the code for this and moves on. How I get it to call this again once all the other statements have been processed is my issue. 
Think I have a not very pretty 'hack' though which I'll post once I've tested it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have batch processing software, then you should have several Given (setup) steps, 1 When (trigger) step, several Then (criteria) steps.

```
Given I have these SEPA bills
 | sepa bill 1 |
 | sepa bill 2 |
And I have these BAC bills
 | bac bill 1 |
 | bac bill 2 |
When the payments are processed
Then these sepa bills are completed
 | sepa bill 1 |
 | sepa bill 2 |
And I these bac bills are completed
 | bac bill 1 |
 | bac bill 2 |
```

It's simpler, easier to read what is supposed to be done, and can be expanded to more. The works should be done in the step definitions of setting up and verifying.